# shorten (subtract) header and remove empty line in fasta file by perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta file like this with headers like this:

```
>GL13245678
ABCDEDERFSE

>GL123456789
ABDFDRAGDTGEGAGFDAS

>GL1254367890
AFGHSRSGFGSHSFG
```

I want to change the header to contain only GL and 6 digits and remove the empty line above each header, like this:

```
>GL132456
ABCDEDERFSE
>GL123456
ABDFDRAGDTGEGAGFDAS
>GL125436
AFGHSRSGFGSHSFG
```

Can anyone share a perl script for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove anything from headers (lines starting with `>`) after GL and 6 digits:

```
s/^>GL\d{6}\K.+//
```

Only print non-empty (whitespace only) lines:

```
print if /\S/
```

Putting it all together:

```
perl -ne 's/^>GL\d{6}\K.+//; print if /\S/' file
```